# What does this Linux command do?

Tags: command-line, compiling, c++

```
g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/thrift *.cpp -lthrift -o something
```

This is from the Apache Thrift website.

Also is the -I/usr supposed to be -I /usr?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a breakdown of the command. First the original command, for reference

```
g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/thrift *.cpp -lthrift -o something
```

Now, for the breakdown.

```
g++
```

This is the actual command command, `g++`. It is the program that is being executed. Here is what it is, from the man page:

> gcc - GNU project C and C++ compiler

This is a compiler for programs written in C++ and C. It takes C or C++ code and turns it into a program, basically.

```
-Wall
```

This part makes it display all warnings when compiling. (Warn All)

```
-I/usr/local/include/thrift
```

This part tells `g++` to use `/usr/local/include/thrift` as the directory to get the header files from. And with the question about whether to put a space after the I or not. You can do it either way. The way the options (options are things in a command after `-` signs. `-Wall` and `-I` are options) are parsed allows you to put a space or not. It depends on your personal preference.

```
*.cpp
```

This part passes every `.cpp` file in the current directory to the `g++` command.

```
-lthrift
```

This can also be `-l thrift`. It tells `g++` to search the `thrift` library when linking.

```
-o something
```

This tells it that when everything is compiled to place the executable in the file `something`.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you should look for the documentation of a command in its [man page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page): `man g++`. In the case of GNU software such as GCC, you'll usually find more complete documentation in [info format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Info_%28Unix%29), or in HTML on the [software home page](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/).

C (and C++) compilers have a somewhat peculiar syntax that doesn't heed the usual conventions for options (options come before operand, there's an optional space between an option and its argument, …). The space after `-I` is actually optional, but `-Wall` needs to be one word.

Here's a quick overview of that command (look in the documentation for details):

- `g++` run a C++ compiler
- `-Wall` emit warnings on suspicious code (`-Wall` actually means important warnings only, not all possible warnings)
- `-I/usr/local/include/thrift` look in that directory for include files (`#include` directives)
- `*.cpp` compile these files
- `-lthrift` link with this library (this searches `libthrift.a`). Note that `-l` must come after the files you're compiling, because `-l` means “if there are any undefined symbols at this point, look for definitions in the specificed library”
- `-o something` put the compiled and linked output into the specified file